# IPP and DEV C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv, intel-ipp

Hi i use DEV C++ compiler in windows xp sp2 and recently i downloaded the IPP libraries. I installed successfully , i set up the compiler directories from option menu to IPP directories but when i try to compile  an ITT program i get linker error for the ITT functions. Is there a solution?

Comment: Why are you using an IDE that was a buggy piece of crap 5 years ago, and hasn't been updated or maintained since? Just upgrade to one of the countless other C++ IDE's available.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it will work.  See:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=60550

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the IPP System requirements (Software) from [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/win/start/release_notes.pdf). You will see that only a Microsoft or Intel Compiler is supported.

> ...
>
> A supported C compiler (Intel IPP has
>   been tested with the following):
>
> - Intel® Parallel Composer
> - Intel® C++ Compiler for Windows* OS versions 10.1, 11.0 and 11.1
> - Microsoft* Visual Studio* 2008
> - Microsoft* Visual Studio* 2005
> - Microsoft* Visual C++* .NET 2003
> - Microsoft* Windows Software Development Kit for Microsoft* Windows
>     Vista

But of course you could always try the library with [VC++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP) Edition.